# Changing style display property in Chrome JavaScript not executed properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I developed the following JS code in Firefox:

```
show_message("Menu is being loaded ...");
load_menu();
hide_message();

function show_message(mesg) {
  mmw_content.textContent = mesg;
  mmw_content.style.display = mmw_shade.style.display = "block";
}

function hide_message() {
  mmw_content.style.display = mmw_shade.style.display = "none";
  mmw_content.textContent = "";
}
```

The CSS for the shade background and the modal message is as follows:

```
/* modal message window */
#mmw_shade {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: silver;
  opacity: 0.25;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#mmw_content {
  display: none;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

The modal message window shows and hides perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome, the showing of the window fails. It seems to be somehow delayed and only showing just before it is hidden, although the loading of the menu in between takes 4 seconds. When i step through the code in debugging mode, it shows however.

Does Chrome JS deal with the program stack in a different way than Firefox?

Comment: Your question ends suddenly...? Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Could you provide some CodeSnippet? I can't seem to reproduce the issue

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I will see what i can do. Never made a code snippet before.

Comment: I have found the reason for the described behavior in Chrome, and found a simple solution. Actually, right after the initial call to show_message(), i am calling a function to log the selection of a certain menu in the database (log_action). I did not include that call in my post, because i thought it was not relevant. This is an async function however, and apparently that makes Chrome decide to delay the showing of the message window. Because if i call log_action() with await in front of it, making it a synchronous call, the message window is shown immediately.